# Using matplotlib limit the frequency of the x ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble limiting the number of dates on the x-axis to make them legible. I need to plot the word length vs the year but the number of years is too large for the plot size.

The Issue:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't plot strings, but actual datetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use datetime (if your dates are in string format, you can easily [convert them to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)). Once you do that it should automatically display years along the x-axis. If you need to change the frequency of ticks to **every** year (or anything else), you can use mdates, like so:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import math

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-2000", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("10-04-2019", "%d-%m-%Y")

x = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
y = [math.sqrt(x) for x in range(len(x))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The snippet above generates the following:
[image]

Comment: How do I change the timedelta to years. I'm getting `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (13879,) and (39,)`

Comment: @Cryoexn, the x and y arrays in my code are just dummy data for the demo. You should use whatever data you were using, except convert the time array into an array of datetime objects. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah I got the date time working with my data now, but I'm still having trouble getting the date time to only show the years. I couldn't find how to do it on the internet.

Comment: Try using `mdates.YearLocator()` similar to how I did it in the code snippet.

Comment: I have that in my code as you did in the example `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())`

Comment: I looked around for other ways to get the date formatted and added the line `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(m_dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))` and now I have a more favorable result than what I had started with. Thank you very much for the help and guidance!

Comment: Yay! Welcome :)